# Want to pass a variable to a partial, that contains a helper name like if or ifequals

Tags: handlebars.js

I would like to pass a partial a variable that contains a helper, so that the partial can better reused, However, my companies installed version of handlebars will not accept new helpers.

**data eg:**

```
{
"orderLines":[
{"unitPrice": "0.46","isItemUnavailable": "Y"},
{"unitPrice": "0.46"}]
}
```

**Template 1:**

```
{{> myPartial helpername="if" totest="isItemUnavailable"}}
```

**Inside myPartial:**

```
{{#each orderLines}}
{{#helpername totest}}
// stuff here if isItemUnavialable
{{/helper}}
{{/each}}
```

The problem as I see it, is that I cannot pass a variable to my partial in order to dynamically set a helper?

The outcome of the above is an error in the partial, saying it cannot find helper "helpername" even though it is supposed to render "if"

Comment: In your partial could you put just this : {{helpername}} and tell us what is displayed by the partial.

Answer (score 0):

The partial passes the variable `if`. But when you place it beside a hash, it no longer accepts it as a variable with a value, but looks for `#helpername` as a registered helper, which then throws an error because there isn't one.